# HAProxy - LB IP address is not delegated to virtual machines

Tags: azure, load-balancing, haproxy, keep-alive

I am total beginner for HAProxy so please any advice will be much useful.
I have two virtual machines on Microsoft Azure.
They are in virtual network, and they have private IP addresses 10.0.9.4 and 10.0.9.5
I created new Network interface on Microsoft Azure in the same virtual network with IP address 10.0.9.7
Of course this is not delegated to any virtual machines.

Name of interface is : `lb.oozie.local`, private IP address `10.0.9.7`

I added in /etc/hosts on .4 and .5

```
10.0.9.7 lb.oozie.local
```

I installed haproxy on both machines 4 and 5.
`haconfig` file is the following:

```
global
log /dev/log local0
log /dev/log local1 notice
chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats timeout 30s
    #user haproxy
    #group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL).
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers kEECDH+aRSA+AES:kRSA+AES:+AES256:RC4-SHA:!kEDH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL

defaults
log global
mode http
option httplog
option dontlognull
timeout connect 5000
timeout client 50000
timeout server 50000

frontend localnodes
bind lb.oozie.local:80
mode http
default_backend nodes

backend nodes
mode http
balance roundrobin
option forwardfor
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
server oozie1 10.0.9.4:11000 check
server oozie2 10.0.9.5:11000 check

listen stats lb.oozie.local:1936
stats enable
stats uri /haproxy?stats
```

I did also:

```
sudo service haproxy restart

Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart haproxy.service
```

Validation returns following:

```
haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -c
[WARNING] 284/134546 (22658) : config : frontend 'GLOBAL' has no 'bind' directive. Please declare it as a backend if this was intended.
Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result FAILED
Total: 3 (2 usable), will use epoll.
Using epoll() as the polling mechanism.
[WARNING] 284/134547 (22658) : Server nodes/oozie2 is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 284/134547 (22658) : sendto logger #1 failed: No such file or directory (errno=2)
[ALERT] 284/134547 (22658) : sendto logger #2 failed: No such file or directory (errno=2)
```

As I understood my servers should get the LB IP address (10.0.9.7).

I try from 10.0.9.4 and 10.0.9.5 ping to 10.0.9.7

but on both servers I am getting it is not recognized.

```
ping 10.0.9.7

PING 10.0.9.7 (10.0.9.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.9.4 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.9.4 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Also if it is relevant:
i installed keepalived mechanism
I did not set public IP address for Load Balancer address, it has only private IP 10.0.9.7, because service is invoked directly from servers 10.0.9.4 and 10.0.9.5

please help.
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Load Balancer in front of VM's with HA Proxy to create a fault tolerant pair of HA Proxies , you need to create an internal Load Balancer with the frontend IP of 10.0.9.7 (rather than assign 10.0.9.7 to a NIC).  It is not possible to ICMP ping the frontend IP of a Load Balancer frontend, you need to use TCP ping instead.  Make sure health probes are configured and see a signal from your HA Proxy VM's directly rather than the port HA Proxy is offering up to clients (the result is probably not what you want).  Familiarize yourself with Standard Load Balancer at https://aka.ms/lbstandard and take not that an NSG must whitelist ports used with a Standard LB.